# How to create a For loop for each Value in Dictionary Array VB?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, dictionary, key-value

I am working in VB script

lets say this my dictionary content

```
KbDictionary.Add("X", {"jump", "refract"})
```

`KbDictionary.Add("Q", {"frag", "donar"})`

how do i create a for loop for each value. like this

`for each st As String in KbDictionary.Values`  which is the incorrect method i tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're working with an **Array** of strings...

So just change:

```
For Each st As String In KbDictionary.Values
```

To:

```
For Each st() As String In KbDictionary.Values
```

*Note the addition of parenthesis to indicate an array.

If you want to work with the Key and the Value at the same time then use a KeyValuePair like this:

```
    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String()) In KbDictionary
        Debug.Print(kvp.Key & " --> " & String.Join(", ", kvp.Value))
    Next
```